# Avoid refreshing the page at pagination

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

I want to avoid refreshing page when i switch the pages using pagination from Laravel because when I switch the page from 1 to page 2, It redirects to the parent page. How can I avoid reloading page when i switch the pages? I have 2 tabs at `Invitation` - `Received` and `Initiated`. On `Initiated`, I have pagination, when i press on page 2 for example, I get redirected to the parent page which is `Invitation`, I need to stay on the page `Initiated` when i switch the page from pagination.

*Here is my controller:*

```php
$initiated =  \App\Invitation::with('user')
    ->where('inviter_id', Sentinel::getUser()->id)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(6);
```

*Here is my view:*

```html
<div id="initiated" class="profile-edit tab-pane fade" style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0;">
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center u-nav-v5-3 u-nav-primary  " role="tablist"
            data-target="nav-5-3-primary-hor-center" data-tabs-mobile-type="slide-up-down"
            data-btn-classes="btn btn-md btn-block u-btn-outline-primary"
            style="display: flex;justify-content: flex-end;">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a a data-toggle="tab" href="#grid" style="font-size: 12px"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> Grid</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a a data-toggle="tab" href="#list" style="font-size: 12px"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> List</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="grid" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <?php $count_user = 0;
         ?>
                @foreach($initiated as $record)
                @if($count_user == 0)
                <div class="row margin-bottom-20 ">
                    @endif
                    <?php $count_user++; ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 sm-margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="profile-blog">
                            <img style="border-radius: 0% !important" class="rounded-x"
                                src="{{ asset('thumbnail') }}/{{ $record->user ? $record->user->profile_picture : '' }}"
                                alt="">
                            <div class="name-location" style="top: 30px;position: relative">
                                @if($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'individuals' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug : '')
                                <i style="font-size: 13px;position: relative;" class="icon-user"></i>
                                @elseif($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'organizations' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug :
                                '')
                                <i style="font-size: 13px;position: relative;"
                                    class="icon-hotel-restaurant-172 u-line-icon-pro fa- fa-lg"></i>
                                @endif
                                <a id="my-link" style="color: #555;text-decoration: none;font-size: 16px"
                                    href="{{ url('') }}/{{ $record->user ? $record->user->username : '' }}">{{ $record->user ? $record->user->username : '' }}</a>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix "></div>
                            <strong style="font-size: 13px"><i style="padding: 5px"
                                    class="icon-real-estate-020 u-line-icon-pro"></i>Location :
                            </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->country->country : '' }} <span
                                class="{{ $record->user ? $record->user->country->flag : '' }}"></span><br>
                            <strong style="font-size: 13px"><i style="padding: 5px"
                                    class="icon-notebook fa-"></i>Industry :
                            </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->industry->industry : '' }}<br>
                            @if($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'organizations' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug : '')
                            @if(isset($record->user->organization_type->organization_type))
                            <strong style="font-size: 13px"><i
                                    class="icon-hotel-restaurant-172 u-line-icon-pro fa- fa-lg"
                                    style="padding: 5px;font-size: 13px"></i>Organization :
                            </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->organization_type->organization_type : '' }}@endif
                            @endif
                            @if($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'individuals' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug : '')
                            @if(!empty($record->user->career_path[0]))
                            <strong style="font-size: 13px"><i class="icon-speedometer"
                                    style="padding: 5px"></i>Function :
                            </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->career_path[0]->functions->function : '' }}@endif
                            @endif
                            <hr>
                            <ul class="list-inline share-list">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/cancel-invitation/{{$record->id}}"><i class="fa fa-times"> </i>Cancel</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @if($count_user == 2)
                </div>
                <?php  $count_user = 0; ?>
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <div id="list" class="tab-pane fade">
                <?php $count_user = 0;
         ?>
                @foreach($initiated as $record)
                @if($count_user == 0)
                <div class="row">
                    @endif
                    <?php $count_user++; ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 sm-margin-bottom-20" style="margin-bottom: 12px">
                        <div class="profile-blog" style="padding: 5px">
                            <img style="margin-right: 10px"
                                src="{{ asset('thumbnail') }}/{{ $record->user ? $record->user->profile_picture : '' }}"
                                alt="">
                            <div class="name-location">
                                <h3> @if($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'individuals' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug :
                                    '')
                                    <i style="font-size: 13px;position: relative;" class="icon-user"></i>
                                    @elseif($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'organizations' ?
                                    $record->user->role[0]->slug : '')
                                    <i style="font-size: 13px;position: relative;"
                                        class="icon-hotel-restaurant-172 u-line-icon-pro fa- fa-lg"></i>
                                    @endif <a id="my-link" style="color: #555;text-decoration: none;font-size: 16px"
                                        href="{{ url('') }}/{{ $record->user ? $record->user->username : '' }}">{{ $record->user ? $record->user->username : '' }}</a>
                                </h3>
                                <ul class="list-inline share-list d-flex pull-right"
                                    style="bottom: 25px;position: relative;margin-bottom: -20px;left: -25px">
                                    <li style="left: 25px;position: relative">
                                        <a href="/cancel-invitation/{{$record->id}}"><i
                                                class="icon-custom-me rounded fa fa-times"> </i></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div style="display: flex;right: 2px;position: relative;bottom: 12px;margin-bottom: -10px">
                                <div style="padding-right: 15px">
                                    <strong><i class="icon-real-estate-020 u-line-icon-pro"></i> :
                                    </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->country->country : '' }} <span
                                        class="{{ $record->user ? $record->user->country->flag : '' }}"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div style="padding-right: 10px">
                                    <strong><i class="icon-screen-tablet fa-"></i> :
                                    </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->industry->industry : '' }}
                                </div>
                                <div style="padding-right: 10px">
                                    @if($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'organizations' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug :
                                    '')
                                    @if(isset($record->user->organization_type->organization_type))
                                    <strong><i class="icon-speedometer"></i> :
                                    </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->organization_type->organization_type : '' }}
                                    @endif
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <div style="padding-right: 10px">
                                    @if($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'individuals' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug :
                                    '')
                                    @if(!empty($record->user->career_path[0]))
                                    <strong><i class="icon-frame fa-"></i> :
                                    </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->career_path[0]->functions->function : '' }}
                                    @endif
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @if($count_user == 2)
                </div>
                <?php  $count_user = 0; ?>
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </dl>
    {!! $initiated->render() !!}
</div>
```

*Here is my Ajax:*

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.pagination a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#initiated').load(url + ' div#initiated');
});
</script>
```

Comment: The usual practice includes (1) using functions like [jQuery.AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to fetch the next page's content region then redraw that of the current page; and (2) rewrite your frontend with frontend javascript framework [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) or [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) then get paged data with some API endpoint that you wrote.

Comment: You cannot do this with php alone.

Comment: Hey, how can I use Ajax on this function? Because I used some Ajax but without success. Please check my updated code, I will put my Ajax here.

Comment: @Andrew, isn't your ajax working?

Comment: @UdoE. not really, still refreshing with this pagination `{{ $initiated->appends(array_merge(request()->all()))->links() }}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably want to use jQuery's [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) on the actual element that you cares instead of rewriting the whole HTML. Perhaps something like this:

```
$('.pagination a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#initiated').load(url + ' div#initiated');
});
```

Remember to re-run this script everytime after new content is loaded with AJAX if the pagination links are rewritten. With the `complete` parameter in the `.load()` function, you can do this:

```
function ajaxPaging() {
    $('.pagination a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#initiated').load(url + ' div#initiated', null, ajaxPaging); // re-run on complete
    });
}
ajaxPaging();
```

**Update:** Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.

You might run into this error on Chrome. To fix it, try this before your other script calls ([reference](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues/799)):

```
(passiveSupported && (active || el == window.document || el == window.document.body || el == window)) ? el.addEventListener(name, fn, { passive: false, capture: bubble }) : el.addEventListener(name, fn, bubble || false);
```

Comment: Hm, is partially working. Because now, my page didn't refreshing, but if I'm on page 2, and I select page 1, 3 or 4, is loading a blank page . Please check this and my updated code . https://imgur.com/a/N4CvqVq

Comment: Sorry. I don't quite understand the situation from your description. What do you mean by your "page didn't refreshing"? Also did you re-run the on click script after load?

Comment: Page didn't reloading, that's what I wanted to say, this is what I needed. What do you mean by `re-run the on click script after load`?

Comment: @Andrew: Updated my answer. Please check and try again.

Comment: Nope...same problem:( When I click on another page, it's reloading a new tab but with no content, like in these photos: https://imgur.com/a/N4CvqVq .

Comment: So it doesn't work even on the first time you click a pagination link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200936/discussion-between-andrew-and-koala-yeung).